# Python multithreaded algorithm is not working efficiently

Tags: python, multithreading, algorithm

I have a function for extracting data from list and generates a matrix form this data.
The list length may have a huge size. So I split data into chunks and I pass it to function to running in a thread.

```
# "n" is number of chunks (also number of threads)
n = 10
length = len(target_data)
s1 = 0
s2 = n
ranges = []

# this loop makes the ranges.(ex [ [0:10],[10:20],[20:30] ] ...)
for i in range(0, int(length/n)):
    if i == int(length/n)-1:
        s2 = -1
    r = [s1,s2]
    s1=s2
    s2=s1+n
    ranges.append(r)
for k in range(0, n):
    # pass main list (target_data) and target range (ranges[k]) to function in a thread
    # and then function only pick piece of list in (ranges[k]) range 
    # result_buffer is a shared list between threads to put results in this list
    t = threading.Thread(target = DataAdapter.matrix_click, args=(target_data, result_buffer, ranges[k]))
    threadpool.append(t)
```

and then I start threads using this code :

```
for th in threadpool:
   th.start()
   th.join()
```

But when I measure run time, the multithreaded algorithm is just *0.319637* sec faster than old non-multithreaded algorithm.
Also when I increase value of the `n` for example `n=10` and I measure run time, its just *0.21393* sec faster than old non-multithreaded algorithm!

how ever I'm not sure multithreading this algorithm in this way decreases the execution time.

My questions:

> **Is it correct that I split my data into chunks and I process each chunk in a thread?**

> **And should I expect that my multithreaded method decrease runtime significantly?**

> **Is there a better way to implement this algorithm?**

Comment: The given information is incomplete. It's not possible to judge about the performance improvement. If the old time was 0.39 s and it is now 0.31 s faster, isn't that great? Do you have a single core machine? Do you run it in a VM? Do you know about Python's GIL? Have you tried multiprocessing? What performance do you expect? How many cores do you have? How much RAM does it use? Is disk swapping involved? What is `target_data`?

Answer (score 3):

I cannot say how effective multi-threading will be in this case, however there is one thing you are doing wrong.

In your snippet you are starting a thread, waiting for it to finish and then starting another one:

```
for th in threadpool:
   th.start()
   th.join()
```

The correct way to start them all at the same time and wait for them would be like this:

```
for th in threadpool:
   th.start()

for th in threadpool:
   th.join()
```

Good luck.